# Which human cell lines do not express the GLP-1 receptor?

Tags: cell-culture

I need a human cell line that does not express the GLP-1 (glucagon like peptide-1) receptor.

I'm working with HeLa cells, do those express the GLP-1 receptor? Which other cell lines exist that don't express this specific receptor?

Are there any general resources where I could find this kind of information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AbCam suggests HeLa cells as positive controls for their [antibody to GLP1R](http://www.abcam.com/GLP1R-antibody-ab119287.html). They provide the following pictures of HeLa cells labeled with their antibody:

[image: HeLa cells labeled with anti-GLP1R]

(The image of the right is treated with synthesized peptide.)

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glucagon-like_peptide_1_receptor), GLP1R is also expressed in pancreatic beta cells and the brain.